# Segmentation fault whilst trying to publish PointCloud

Tags: ros-kinetic, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to publish a PointCloud so that I can visualise it in RViz, however even though my node will compile I get a segmentation fault when I run it.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud.h>
    
int main(int argc, char **argv){
        // Initialise ROS and set up a node
        ros::init(argc, argv, "send_numbers");
        ros::NodeHandle nh;
    
    //Creates the publisher, and tells it to publish to a topic
ros::Publisher pub = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud>("number", 5);
//initialise random function
srand (time(0));

//Sets the loop to publish at a rate of 1Hz
ros::Rate rate(1);

while(ros::ok()) {
 sensor_msgs::PointCloud msg;
     msg.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
 msg.header.frame_id = "/map";
 for(unsigned int i  =  0; i < 100; ++i){
 msg.points[i].x = rand() % 10;
     msg.points[i].y = rand() % 10;
 msg.points[i].z = rand() % 2;
     }
 pub.publish(msg);
     rate.sleep();
}
}
```

This is my gdb output

```
   Reading symbols from devel/lib/number_output/number_output...done.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/dan/catkin_ws/devel/lib/number_output/number_output 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7ffff1855700 (LWP 21659)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe9054700 (LWP 21660)]
[

New Thread 0x7ffff1054700 (LWP 21661)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff0853700 (LWP 21666)]

Thread 1 "number_output" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000040cdb0 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdaa8)
    at /home/dan/catkin_ws/src/number_output/src/send_numbers.cpp:25
25       msg.points[i].x = rand() % 10;
(gdb)
```

Sorry for the funny format. I'm not sure what happened there. I'm new to ROS so if any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298400/segmentation-fault-whilst-trying-to-publish-pointcloud/) by [DRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/36624/dros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2018-07-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think I worked it out, the msg.points array doesn't have a size allocated before assigning values to it. I had to put msg.points.resize(num_points) to assign it the correct size before assignment.

Thanks for looking!
Dan

---

Originally posted by [DRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/36624/dros/) with karma: 23 on 2018-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-07-24**:
You are correct. The points member is a `std::vector` object you can either set the size then add the data (fastest) or you can use the `push_back` method to add elements one by one (slower)

**Comment by [DRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/36624/dros/) on 2018-07-24**:
Thanks for the reply Pete.

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2018-07-24**:
Can you mark this as answered?

**Comment by [DRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/36624/dros/) on 2018-07-25**:
Sure, sorry about that. All done.